# Locked SQL Server UDF

Tags: sql-server

When I try to `RENAME/DELETE` a specific `UDF` I get the following error:

> "Lock request time out period exceeded (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)"

Note that If I try to `ALTER` it, the query runs indefinitely..

Here's what I did to try solving the problem without success:

1) `DBCC opentran()` returns "No active open transactions."

2) `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` returns 0.

3) BlkBy field returned by the `sp_who2` is empty.

4) I both restarted windows server and manually stopped/restarted MSSQLServer service

5) `chkdsk c:` returns:

```
   976657407 KB total disk space.
   114105840 KB in 702392 files.
      424472 KB in 122799 indexes.
           0 KB in bad sectors.
     1885591 KB in use by the system.
       65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   860241504 KB available on disk.
```

No problem with all other database objects

Comment: Is that UDF used by a view maybe ?

Comment: No, I never use views, this UDF is invoked only within various stored procedures

Comment: So if you would be able to rename the udf than all these stored procedures would become invalid ? Maybe you need to drop the stored procs first, rename the udf, and then recreate the stored procs ? I dont know for sure I am just guessing here

Comment: Have you checked dependencies?  From SSMS, right click on the UDF and choose *View Dependencies* from the menu.  Perhaps you have a computed column that relies on this udf?

Comment: Ok but it seems that no one is blocking tht UDF so why I cannot rename/alter/delete it? In addition this UDF is not new... I created it some months ago and it worked fine up to 1 hour ago... I was only trying to ALTER it by adding a couple of stupid instructions ...

Comment: No computed columns rely on this UDF